# React: Tailwind CSS with DaisyUI Error: Object.hasOwn is not a function

Tags: reactjs, node.js, tailwind-css, intellisense, daisyui

My Tailwind CSS Intellisense extension is giving me this error in the output:
[Error - 7:41:37 PM] Tailwind CSS: Object.hasOwn is not a function
TypeError: Object.hasOwn is not a function

Tailwind Config file:

```
    /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  plugins: [require('daisyui')],
  daisyui: {
    themes: [
      {
        lightTheme: {
          primary: "#f4aa3a",
          secondary: "#f4f4a1",
          accent: "#1be885",
          neutral: "#272136",
          "base-100": "#ffffff",
          info: "#778ad4",
          success: "#23b893",
          warning: "#f79926",
          error: "#ea535a",
          body: {
            "background-color": "#e3e6e6",
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nextjs-ecommerce",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.3",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.4.2",
    "daisyui": "^3.9.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "next": "13.5.4",
    "next-auth": "^4.23.2",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.5.6",
    "prisma": "^5.4.2",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "zod": "^3.22.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.5.4",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

Things I tried:

1. Reinstalling Tailwind CSS Intellisense extension
2. Upgrading NodeJS from V18.16.0 to 20.9.0 (both versions are well above
   DaisyUI's requirement as per their documentation)
3. Reinstalling NodeJS completely
4. Disabling Tailwind CSS Intellisense extension and re-enabling it
5. Restarting VS code
6. Removing all daisyui packages and reinstalling them with npm

If I remove the 'require(daisyui)' from the plugins, everything works fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Having this problem, but with husky pre-commit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved after reinstalling VS code and setting up the dev environment completely from scratch.